# Missing required keys: [:id] - Routing to a view for each instance of my model with its unique ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, routes

I'm working on a job board to learn/practice rails. I have a separate view for each job category, and I want the user to be able to click on a particular job posting to access another view with all of the listing's details. I've partially figured out the routing, as I'm able to go to localhost:3000/jobs/listing/7 for example to see the view for the listing of id:7. I'm having a problem linking to the /listing/:id from my job category view, and can only access a view for a specific id by typing it into the address bar. I've been working on this for days and checked out many related questions on here, but can't seem to figure it out. I believe I'm overlooking a simple, but critical detail, since i'm not very experienced with rails.

Here is my job category view:

```
<div class="cat-banner" id="developer">
    <h1>Human Resources Jobs</h1>
    <h4 class="listing-count"><%= Job.where(:category => 'Human Resources').count.to_s + ' Listings' %></h4>
</div>

<div class="category-page">
    <!-- Full-Stack Developer Jobs -->
    <div class="jobs-posted">
        <hr class="other-line">
        <% if Job.where(:category => 'Human Resources').count > 0 %>
            <% @jobs.each do |job| %>
                <div class="job">
                    <% if job.category == "Human Resources" %>
                        <span class="job-logo"><%= image_tag('salesforce.png', :size => "60x40") %></span>
                        <span id="line-align"><p class="title"><%= link_to job.title, listing_path(@job) %> </p>                
<p class="name"><%= job.name %></p></span>

                        <% if job.location == "Remote" %>
                            <span class="remote-tag"><%= job.location.upcase %></span>
                        <% else %>
                            <p class="location"><%= job.location %></p>
                        <% end %>

                        <p class="kind"><%= job.kind %></p>
                        <p class="time-stamp"><%= job.created_at.strftime("%A, %B %d %Y") %></p>
                        <hr class="line">
                    <% end %>
                </div>
            <% end %>
        <% else %>
            <p>There are no human resources jobs at the moment...</p>
            <p style="text-decoration: underline;"><%= link_to 'Post a Human Resources Job Here', new_job_path %></p>
        <% end %>
    </div>
    <!-- End of Human Resources Jobs -->
</div>
```

And my routes.rb file:

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'subscribers' => 'subscribers#index'
 
  get 'jobs/remote' => 'jobs#remote'

  get 'jobs/listing/:id' => 'jobs#listing', as: 'listing'

  get 'jobs/company' => 'jobs#company'

  get 'jobs/dev' => 'jobs#dev'

  get 'jobs/design' => 'jobs#design'

  get 'jobs/marketing' => 'jobs#marketing'

  get 'jobs/ai' => 'jobs#ai'

  get 'jobs/fullstack' => 'jobs#fullstack'

  get 'jobs/frontend' => 'jobs#frontend'

  get 'jobs/backend' => 'jobs#backend'

  get 'jobs/it' => 'jobs#it'

  get 'jobs/software' => 'jobs#software' 

  get 'jobs/product' => 'jobs#product'

  get 'jobs/cloud' => 'jobs#cloud'

  get 'jobs/mobile' => 'jobs#mobile'

  get 'jobs/database' => 'jobs#database'

  get 'jobs/datascience' => 'jobs#datascience'

  get 'jobs/blockchain' => 'jobs#blockchain' 

  get 'jobs/security' => 'jobs#security'

  get 'jobs/support' => 'jobs#support'

  get 'jobs/network' => 'jobs#network'

  get 'jobs/finance' => 'jobs#finance'

  get 'jobs/sales' => 'jobs#sales'

  get 'jobs/hr' => 'jobs#hr' 

  get 'jobs/businessdev' => 'jobs#businessdev'

  resources :jobs

  
  root 'jobs#index'

  get 'jobs/index'

  get 'jobs/new'
```

And part of the Jobs Controller:

```
    class JobsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @jobs = Job.all
    @subscribers = Subscriber.all
  end
  def new
    @job = Job.new
  end

  def listing
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
  end
  def show
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
  end
  def create
    @job = Job.new(params.require(:job).permit(:title, :url, :category, :kind, :location, :description, :name, :summary, :website, :email, :companyDescription, :headquarters ))
    

    if @job.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render "new"
    end

    respond_to :html, :json
  end
```

I've tried:

```
<%= link_to job.title, listing_path(@job) %> 
<%= link_to job.title, listing_path(@job.id) %> 
<%= link_to job.title, listing_path(@job[:id]) %> 
<%= link_to job.title, listing_path %>
```

and other variations that I thought would work from reading StackOverflow

I believe my problem comes from this link_to statement (wrong syntax?), as everything looks alright in my jobs controller and routes file.

I either get:
No route matches {:action=>"listing", :controller=>"jobs", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id],

or

undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass,

or

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

The "missing required keys: [:id]" error is confusing me. I've checked out many resources trying to figure out how to pass the :id but can't solve it.

This is my first post on here and I REALLY appreciate any help and look forward to being knowledgeable enough in the future so I can answer questions too.

[rake routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBKTz.png)

Comment: Can you look in your generated HTML what is the value it's producing from `listing_path(@job)`?

Comment: The HTML isn't being generated, i'm getting the error: ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Jobs#hr - No route matches {:action=>"listing", :controller=>"jobs", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view that you are putting as example is using the instance variable **@jobs**. According with your controller that would be your index action where you don't have **@job** defined

**Note:** Notice on that view you are using **@jobs** and **job** on your iterator

So I think if you change @job for job that would fix the problem on that view

```
<%= link_to job.title, listing_path(job) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error clearly states, your path is expecting a job id but it is not getting one, so inspecting your call for the path, in line:

```
<span id="line-align"><p class="title"><%= link_to job.title, listing_path(@job) %> </p>
```

you are passing `@job` as param to the listing path.

change it to `job` so it would be:

```
<span id="line-align"><p class="title"><%= link_to job.title, listing_path(job) %> </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the missing id, you should do:

```
<%= link_to job.title, listing_path(id: @job) %>
```

since your id is stored in the variable `@job`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the reason this isn't working is because you are not sending the correct argument to your `link_to` here:

```
<%= link_to job.title, listing_path(@job) %>
```

You have to remember that you are iterating through all your `@jobs` and calling each individual job with the `job` variable between the | |. You are trying to create a link to each individual job, so the correct link_to should be:

```
<%= link_to job.title, listing_path(job) %>
```

Where `job` is the individual job that the `link_to` is looking for.